# Is the output of sqlite in "mode .insert" correct?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, data-munging

Consider the table I create in SQLite database with `CREATE TABLE tbl(x);` which has the following data: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(1); INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(2);`.  Now I wish to create a SQL file of this schema and data that I wish to import into PostgreSQL and I do the following:

```
.mode insert
.output "tbl.sql"
.schema tbl
select * from tbl order by x;
.output stdout
```

And the output is:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(x);
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO table VALUES(2);
```

Shouldn't the output of the insert statements be `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(1); INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(2);` ?

This is not really a problem because I can easily do a find/repalce to fix this but that might potentially introduce unforeseen problems (like changing data inside the insert statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine SQLite manual](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#changing_output_formats):

> When specifying insert mode, you have to give an extra argument which is the name of the table to be inserted into. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> .mode insert new_table
> sqlite> select * from tbl1;
> INSERT INTO "new_table" VALUES('hello',10);
> INSERT INTO "new_table" VALUES('goodbye',20);
> sqlite>
> ```

So saying `.mode insert` leaves SQLite to use the default table name which is apparently `table`. You should be saying:

```
.mode insert tbl
```

Comment: OOPS!!  I don't know how I missed this in the manual.  Many thanks "mu is too short"!